# Laravel $request->collect() does not pass files to service

Tags: laravel

I have this route:

`Route::post('/user', [UsersController::class, 'storeUser'])`

function in controller:

```
   public function storeUser(Request $request)
    {
        $result = $this->userService->storeUser($request->collect());
    }
```

function in service:

```
    public function storeUser(Collection $data): array
    {
      // why I can not access any files from the request here
      // though if I change to $request->all() in the controller function I can access image file easy
      // what is wrong with collect() and Collection class injected in this function ?
    }
```

Comment: because a collection doesn't consist files !!

Comment: can you explain more please @OMi. Or how can I find this in docs to understand more. Thanks so much.

Comment: The OP has a valid point. Since, `$request->all()` can return everything in an array including files why `$request->collect()` doesn't include the files?

Comment: **If** this is the case, and you expect a different behaviour, then please ask the Laravel maintainers about their choice to handle it this way

Comment: If you take some time surfing through `Laravel`'s implementation of collect you'll find some clues explaining this behavior. The first clue is `$this->getInputSource()->all() + $this->query->all()` in `Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithInput::collect` method that checks whether or not you've supplied an array to `collect`, in your case you didn't so the `else` part kicks in and `$this->input($key)` is called (`$key` is `null` because you didn't pass a value to `collect` so it defaults to `null`). Now if we look at `Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithInput::input`, *see next comment...*

Comment: what `Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithInput::input` does is getting the wanted piece of data from `$this->getInputSource()->all() + $this->query->all()`. `$this->query->all()` will return the parameters from the query string. `$this->getInputSource()->all()` will check the request method, your case it's `POST` and the content type should be `multipart/formdata` (I assume because you're talking about uploading files) so `$this->getInputSource()->all()` will return the parameters from `$_POST` super-global *(see my next comment...)*

Comment: What we have now, based on your call to `collect` you'll get data from the query string, `$_GET` (assuming it's empty as we're talking about `POST` requests here even though you can still send `GET` parameters in a `POST` request). And also from `$_POST` and as in `PHP` files are stored in another super-global called `$_FILES`, your call to `collect` won't include any file.

Comment: A workaround might be merging `$request->collect()` with `$request->allFiles()` that returns the files from the request (from `$_FILES` super-global).

Comment: @MMahfouz You're welcome! Feel free to ask for any other explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the `$request->collect()` with files:

```
$result = $this->userService->storeUser(
    $request->collect()->merge($request->file())
);
```